# Best practice to update values in the table using AngularJS

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, jquery-ui

I am trying to create 3-way binding using AngularJS to have possibility to change values in the table and localStorage dynamically. I am also using jqueryUI dialog-window, where I want to update values, then save it to the table and to the localStorage. Whith the help of `ng-model` directive I am filling values to the dialog-window. Then on `accept` button I am saving values to the localStorage, and to the table:

```
                data.name = $scope.dialogName;
                data.author = $scope.dialogAuthor;
                data.genre = $scope.dialogGenre;
                data.price = $scope.dialogPrice;

            self.book.name = $scope.dialogName;
            self.book.author = $scope.dialogAuthor;
            self.book.genre = $scope.dialogGenre;
            self.book.price = $scope.dialogPrice;
```

But I think that this is a bad idea(this code doesn't work) and there must be better way to achieve my goal. Thank you.

Below this question you can find codeSnippet, which can give you understanding of my code.

```js
books = [
  {
    "name": "Javascript",
    "author": "David Flanagan",
    "genre": "learning",
    "price": "100"
  },
  {
    "name": "PHP",
    "author": "Luke Welling",
    "genre": "learning",
    "price": "120"
  },
  {
    "name": "Learning JavaScript Design Patterns",
    "author": "Addy Osmani",
    "genre": "learning",
    "price": "400"
  },
  {
    "name": "Understanding ECMAScript 6",
    "author": "Nicholas C. Zakas",
    "genre": "learning",
    "price": "204"
  },
  {
    "name": "Programming JavaScript Applications",
    "author": "Eric Elliot",
    "genre": "learning",
    "price": "214"
  },
  {
    "name": "The C Programming Language",
    "author": "Brian W. Kernighan",
    "genre": "learning",
    "price": "514"
  },
  {
    "name": "Programming Pearls",
    "author": "Jon L. Bentley",
    "genre": "learning",
    "price": "114"
  },
  {
    "name": "Java Concurrency in Practice",
    "author": "Brian Goetz",
    "genre": "learning",
    "price": "140"
  }
]

var app = angular.module('app', []);

app.controller('appCtrl', function ($scope, $http) {
    $scope.title = "Angular Books List";
    $scope.books = books;

    $scope.addNewTask = function () {
        $scope.books = JSON.parse(localStorage['table']);
        $scope.books.push({
            name: $scope.bookName,
            author: $scope.bookAuthor,
            genre: $scope.bookGenre,
            price: $scope.bookPrice
        });
        $scope.bookName = "";
        $scope.bookAuthor = "";
        $scope.bookGenre = "";
        $scope.bookPrice = "";
        localStorage.setItem("table", JSON.stringify($scope.books));

    };

    $scope.ShowConfirm = function () {
        if ( window.confirm("Are you sure?")) {
            var local = JSON.parse(localStorage['table']);
            for (var i = 0; i < local.length; i++) {
                if (local[i].name == this.book.name) {
                    local.splice(i, 1);
                    $scope.books.splice(i, 1);
                    console.log(local);
                    console.log(i);
                    localStorage.setItem("table", JSON.stringify(local));
                    break;
                }
            }
        } else {

        }
    };

    $scope.enableEditor = function(book){
        var self = this,
            data;
      
        $scope.selectedBook = book;
        $scope.dialogBook = angular.copy(book);


        $('#editDisplay').dialog({
            modal: true,
            resizable: false,
            width: 400,
            buttons: {
                Accept: function () {
                    $(this).dialog("close");
                  
                    angular.copy($scope.dialogBook,$scope.selectedBook);
                    localStorage.setItem("table", JSON.stringify($scope.books));

                },
                Cancel: function () {
                    $(this).dialog("close");
                }
            }
        });

    };

    $scope.predicate = 'name';
    $scope.reverse = false;
    $scope.order = function (predicate) {
        $scope.reverse = ($scope.predicate === predicate) ? !$scope.reverse : false;
        $scope.predicate = predicate;
    };
});
```

```css
.sortorder:after {
  content: '\25b2';
}
.sortorder.reverse:after {
  content: '\25bc';
}
.addBookInputs input {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 250px;
}
.addBookInputs {
  margin-bottom: 40px;
}
input::-webkit-outer-spin-button,
 input::-webkit-inner-spin-button {
   /* display: none; */
   -webkit-appearance: none;
   margin: 0;
 }
```

```html
<link href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<body ng-app="app">


<div class="container" ng-controller="appCtrl">
    <div class="page-header">
        <h1>
            {{title}}
        </h1>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-3 col-md-offset-9 col-lg-3 col-lg-offset-9">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="searchField" placeholder="search book...">
        <br>
        <br>

    </div>


    <div class="panel">
        <div class="addBookInputs">
            <input class="form-control" ng-model="bookName" placeholder="type name of the book"/>
            <input class="form-control" ng-model="bookAuthor" placeholder="type author of the book"/>
            <input class="form-control" ng-model="bookGenre" placeholder="type genre of the book"/>
            <input class="form-control" ng-model="bookPrice" placeholder="type price of the book" type="number"/>
            <span class="">
                <button class="btn btn-success" ng-click="addNewTask()">Add Book</button>
            </span>
        </div>



        <table class="table table-hover table-bordered table-">
            <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>
                    <a href="" ng-click="order('name')">Book Name</a>
                    <span class="sortorder" ng-show="predicate === 'name'" ng-class="{reverse:reverse}"></span>
                </th>


                </th>
                <th>
                    <a href="" ng-click="order('author')">Author</a>
                    <span class="sortorder" ng-show="predicate === 'author'" ng-class="{reverse:reverse}"></span>
                </th>
                <th>
                    <a href="" ng-click="order('genre') ">Genre</a>
                    <span class="sortorder" ng-show="predicate === 'genre'" ng-class="{reverse:reverse}"></span>

                </th>
                <th>
                    <a href="" ng-click="order('price')">Price</a>
                    <span class="sortorder" ng-show="predicate === 'price'" ng-class="{reverse:reverse}"></span>
                </th>


                <th>Delete?</th>
            </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
            <tr ng-repeat="book in books | filter:searchField | orderBy:predicate:reverse" ng-hide="book.done">
                <td>
                    {{book.name}}
                </td>
                <td>
                    {{book.author}}
                </td>
                <td>
                    {{book.genre}}
                </td>
                <td>
                    {{book.price | currency}}
                </td>
                <td>
                    <button ng-click = "enableEditor(book)" class="btn btn-warning" > edit </button>
                    <button ng-click = "ShowConfirm()" class="btn btn-danger" > delete </button>
                </td>
                <!--<td>-->
                        <!--<span style="{{setStyle(book.done)}}">-->
                            <!--{{showText(book.done)}}-->
                        <!--</span>-->
                <!--</td>-->
            </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>

        <div id="editDisplay" class="form-horizontal" style="display:none" title="editor">
            <div class="control-group">
                <label class="control-label">id</label>

                <div class="controls">
                    <input class="input-block-level form-control" type="number" disabled>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="control-group">
                <label class="control-label">name</label>

                <div class="controls">
                    <input class="input-block-level form-control" type="text" ng-model = "dialogBook.name">
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="control-group">
                <label class="control-label">author</label>

                <div class="controls">
                    <input class="input-block-level form-control" type="text" ng-model = "dialogBook.author">
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="control-group">
                <label class="control-label">genre</label>

                <div class="controls">
                    <input class="input-block-level form-control" type="text" ng-model="dialogBook.genre">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="control-group">
                <label class="control-label">price</label>

                <div class="controls">
                    <input class="input-block-level form-control" type="number" ng-model = "dialogBook.price">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>


</body>
```

Comment: *"this code doesn't work*" isn't a proper problem description. What does or doesn't work? Any errors? Provide more details

Comment: Not entirely sure what you're trying to achieve.  Are you trying to eliminate repetitive code? if so, use book objects instead of individual properties.  Are you trying to make sure the book array is automatically saved to local storage on each change?  If so, $watchCollection or $watch the book array and save it when changes are detected or use angular-localforage and bind the array directly to localstorage.  If you want clarification either of those techniques, let us know.  If it's neither of those problems, maybe a clarification of the question would help.

Comment: @Beartums sorry for misunderstandings. All I want is to make possible edit function, which will: 1. Save data in localstorage. 2. Dynamically change value in the table. And I achieved saving data in localstorage, but I can't see changes in the table before page reloads. So the question is how to make it possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@max, I think I understand, but bear with me if this isn't helpful.  First, for clarity, I would use objects here.  Use a newBook object to add new books

```
    <div class="addBookInputs">
        <input class="form-control" ng-model="newBook.bookName" placeholder="type name of the book"/>
        <input class="form-control" ng-model="newBook.bookAuthor" placeholder="type author of the book"/>
        <input class="form-control" ng-model="newBook.bookGenre" placeholder="type genre of the book"/>
        <input class="form-control" ng-model="newBook.bookPrice" placeholder="type price of the book" type="number"/>
        <span class="">
            <button class="btn btn-success" ng-click="addNewTask()">Add Book</button>
        </span>
    </div>
```

then, in the controller, You only need to get the value of the array in local storage during initial setup (also, I think the syntax of your retrieval from localstorage is wrong).  In the Add() function, I would simply add the new book to the array and then save the array to the local storage.

```
$scope.books = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('table'));

$scope.newBook = {};

$scope.addNewTask = function () {
    $scope.books.push(newBook);
    $scope.newBook = {};
    localStorage.setItem("table", JSON.stringify($scope.books));
};
```

For the edit dialog, I would pass the book object (book) and an angular.copy of book (editBook).  Then when the edits are approved (in editBook), you should be able to angular.copy(editBook,book) without breaking the reference.  You changes should appear in books and then you can save them to local storage.

Does this help?

UPDATE: Edit functionality.  (I suggest you learn [AngularUI](https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/).  JQuery is considered an anti-pattern for angular apps)

First, in the html, you should change the ng-click attribute of your edit button to be `ng-click="enableEditor(book)"` so that you pass the book reference to your function.  Then the function can be:

```
$scope.enableEditor = function(book){
    $scope.selectedBook = book;
    $scope.dialogBook = angular.copy(book)

    $('#editDisplay').dialog({
        modal: true,
        resizable: false,
        width: 400,
        buttons: {
            Accept: function () {
                $(this).dialog("close");
                $timeout(function() {
                    angular.copy($scope.dialogBook,$scope.selectedBook);
                    localStorage.setItem("table", JSON.stringify($scope.books));
                })
            },
            Cancel: function () {
                $(this).dialog("close");
            }
        }
    });
};
```

You'll need to pass $timeout to the controller just like $html (this allows angular to pick up the asynchronous change from the dialog).  You'll also need to change the html of your dialog to reference dialogBook.name, dialogBook.genre, etc.  Lastly, the 'number' type in your price input field won't work because you have a decimal point (I'd just change it to text and do my validation separately).

You can find a working fiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/beartums/zn5015gt/2/)

Comment: Wow! Thank you for good example of adding new book to my table. This is really nice solution. And very simple) But can you be more specific in describing EDIT function. Thank you

Comment: @max, Cool.  Glad it helps.  I've updated the answer for your edit functionality -- I don't know jqueryUI, so you might have to look at the concepts rather than the specific code.

Comment: During your reccomendations I made fixies in my code snippet above. But unfortunately it doesn't work. Maybe I am doing something wrong?

Comment: Yeah.  Your localstorage reference at the beginning of addNewTask is still wrong.

Comment: Made changes to the answer again to explain some additional needed changes.  Hope they help.

Comment: Yes, you are write. But the problems with edit functions are still here. It doesn't change values in table dynamically.

Comment: OOPS.  Didn't give the correct URL: https://jsfiddle.net/beartums/zn5015gt/4/.  The problem is with not wrapping the data update in the $timeout after the ansynchronous modal update

Comment: Thank you. You helped me very much. But is it good practise to use timeout function? And why do you used it?

Comment: Yes, it is standard practice.  Angular doesn't know about most updates made asynchronously, so the $timeout function just tells it to wait until the next digest cycle so that the watchers will catch it.